# Prevent a Webform to be submitted with AngularJs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am developing a application with asp.net webform and angularJs. I have a form. the form loads data in tabular format. there are a Edit button on each row. the purpose of edit button is to edit the row. type of edit button is 'submit'. so when i click the edit button it refreshes the form. But I want to prevent this to be happening. so i have written a method in my controller. but it's not working. the code is given bellow:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server" ng-submit="sendForm(form1)">
<button type="submit" ng-hide="editMode" ng-click="editMode = true; editItem(item)">Edit</button>
```

controller

```
$scope.editItem = function (index) {
        $scope.editing = $scope.items.indexOf(index);        
    };

$scope.sendForm = function(form) {               
        //console.log("send form is working");        
        return false;
    };
```

One way to solve the problem is to use **'preventDefault()'** in sendForm function. But i would like to know why 'retunr false' is not working here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In controller write the following function

```
$scope.sendForm = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();        
};
```

In aspx page for the form tage add the following directive:

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" runat="server" ng-submit="sendForm($event)">
```